# Python 3.6 Path Confusion

Tags: python, macos, path, pip, python-3.5

I'm having issues when running the "python3" command along with "pip3" to install several python modules. It seems like my pip3 is linked to python 3.6 (which is what I want to use), but python3 is linked to 3.5. See below :

```
pip3 --version
    pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

python3 --version
    Python 3.5.2
```

I'd like to run python3.6, and I am thinking that my PATH variable may be incorrect (or something to that extent). Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

configure your `.bash_profile` like this

`alias python3='python3.6'`

//Setting PATH for Python 3.6

//The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave

`PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"`

`export PATH`

hope it will help.

Comment: This didn't change anything. I am using zshell and edited my .zprofile, and also edited .bash_profile, and both of them don't work. I also tested this in bash as well, still didn't work.

Comment: okey. can you please run this command on terminal and then check again `source ~/.bash_profile` and also give restart your pc.